# Visualforce Page Displays in Chatter Quick Action, But Post/Share Button is Missing

Tags: visualforce, chatter, publisher

I'm fairly new to VF, so please go easy on me. Here's what I've done and what I'm trying to do: 

 - I created a visualforce (vf) page with 5 text labels and 5 input fields.

 - I created a quick action to display the vf page as Chatter action called "WeatherTemplate".

 - The vf page displays, but **the "Share" button is missing.**

 - How do I get the "Share" button/bar to display at the bottom of my vf action page?

(1) **Chatter** tab > **WeatherTemplate** Quick Action Button displays this VF page.

[image]

(2) **Result after entering data and pressing submit button.**

[image]

(3) **This button (or bar) is missing from both pictures, so I can't post my results.** Help is appreciated.

[image]

**Visualforce Code:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the recommendations above, I was able to piece together what I needed. I ended up coding it slightly different than how I began, but here's my basic solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to code the button in the Visualforce page and code the button's action in the page's controller.  The "Pages for Global Custom Actions" code samples in Salesforce Help make up a global custom action that creates a case:

[image]:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_vf_pages_for_custom_actions.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it appears that their code references an object, or objects. Is it possible to code my example without having to reference an object? I'm not looking to store data, but instead just have the information exist in the Chatter feed as if were typed it there. Just like an ordinary comment.

Answer (score 0):

Chatter posts are stored in the FeedItem object, so that you may want to study the sample code with that in mind and review some of the documentation and code samples about the FeedItem object.

Comment: I will do just that. I hadn't fully considered the FeedItem object. I will go back and attack my puzzle from this angle, and then post my results. Thanks 'Scott_in_London' and 'Bonehelmet' for the replies 